# Is it possible to have recursive sum type, with each 'level' having distinct value?

Tags: haskell

I was wondering if it is possible (I guess it is :) ) to have recursive sum type where we have a value of type X on every level, but somehow restrict ourselves that on every level of recursion we have distinct value of X?

For example, if I have

```hs
data MachineType = Worker | Flyer | Digger | Observer | Attacker
data Machine = Single MachineType | Multi MachineType Machine
```

type system would allow me to construct Machine with following type:

```hs
Multi Worker (Multi Worker (Single Worker))
```

but I want this to be restricted, so that only different MachineType-s are allowed.

Is there a way to encode this in type system?

You can just point me in the right direction, as I kinda don't know what to google :) (haskell set-like recursive sum types?)

Comment: You could use a phantom type parameter which is a type level HList of MachineTypes and make Machine a GADT where the constructor requires a proof that the list contains no machine of the given type already

Comment: @sara's comment is certainly one way to do it, but wouldn't it be simpler to just use [`Data.Set`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.26/containers-0.6.0.1/Data-Set.html) and do `newtype Machine = Machine { getMachines :: Set MachineType }`?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I will look into HLists and GADTs to see how they work. I was thinking about sets as well, but was wondering if this could be done one level 'above'. Waht I wanted to encode is something like _'X with addition of Y'_ and set could be interpreted as both _'X with addition of Y'_ and _'Y with addition of X'_. With pattern matching, I would first need to deal with 'main' thing, that is X, and then recurse downwards to its other components, if I want to. But its definitely and option if I don't figure how other solution works :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution is to specify that you can't extend a `Machine` with a duplicate `MachineType`. For that we first need a [singleton](https://blog.jle.im/entry/introduction-to-singletons-1.html) type for `MachineType`:

```
{-# language TypeInType, GADTs, TypeOperators, ConstraintKinds,
    UndecidableInstances, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Kind
import GHC.TypeLits

data MachineType = Worker | Flyer | Digger | Observer | Attacker

data SMachineType t where
  SWorker   :: SMachineType Worker
  SFlyer    :: SMachineType Flyer
  SDigger   :: SMachineType Digger
  SObserver :: SMachineType Observer
  SAttacker :: SMachineType Attacker
```

Then we specify a constraint which is satisfiable if something is not contained in a list of `MachineType`s, and otherwise throws a [custom type error](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#custom-compile-time-errors):

```
type family NotElem (x :: MachineType) (xs :: [MachineType]) :: Constraint where
  NotElem x '[]       = ()
  NotElem x (x ': xs) = TypeError
    (Text "Duplicate MachineTypes are not allowed in Machines" :$$:
    (Text "Can't add " :<>: ShowType x :<>: Text " to "
     :<>: ShowType (x ': xs)))
  NotElem x (y ': xs) = NotElem x xs
```

Then `Machine` is given as a GADT indexed by lists of `MachineType`s:

```
data Machine (ts :: [MachineType]) where
  Single :: SMachineType t -> Machine '[ t ]
  Multi  :: NotElem t ts => SMachineType t -> Machine ts -> Machine (t ': ts)
```

The following definition has inferred type `Machine '[ 'Flyer, 'Digger, 'Worker]`:

```
m1 = Multi SFlyer (Multi SDigger (Single SWorker))
```

The following definition throws a type error:

```
m2 = Multi SFlyer (Multi SFlyer (Single SWorker))
```

With the error message being:

```
   Notes.hs:30:6: error: …
    • Duplicate MachineTypes are not allowed in Machines
      Can't add 'Flyer to '[ 'Flyer, 'Worker]
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and explanations along the way. Got it working, now I'll take some time to go through tutorials like the ones you posted about _singleton_  library to get a feeling 'why' it's working. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It seems I was beaten to it! As a complement to András' answer, I came up with a version that is similar, but uses value level proofs of the uniqueness of each machine type.

This is probably less ergonomic in practical use cases, but it does have a certain "proof relevant mathematics" charm (or so I delude myself into thinking!)

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Prelude

import Data.Kind (Type)
import Data.Void (Void)
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))

data MachineType
  = Worker
  | Flyer
  | Digger
  | Observer
  | Attacker
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data In xs x where
  Here :: forall k (xs :: [k]) (x :: k)
    . In (x ': xs) x
  There :: forall k (xs :: [k]) (x :: k) (y :: k)
    . In xs x -> In (y ': xs) x

type family Not a where
  Not a = (a -> Void)

data Machine :: [MachineType] -> Type where
  Single :: forall (t :: MachineType) (proxy :: MachineType -> Type)
    . proxy t -> Machine '[t]
  Multi :: forall (t :: MachineType) (ts :: [MachineType]) (proxy :: MachineType -> Type)
    . Not (In ts t) -> proxy t -> Machine ts -> Machine (t ': ts)

simpleMachine :: Machine '[ 'Worker ]
simpleMachine = Single Proxy

multiMachine :: Machine '[ 'Flyer, 'Attacker ]
multiMachine = Multi p (Proxy @'Flyer) $ Single (Proxy @'Attacker)
  where
    p :: Not (In '[ 'Attacker ] 'Flyer)
    p = \case
      There l -> case l of
```